# Можно ли составить баг репорт без шагов и ожидаемых результатов?

Tags: юнит-тесты

Мне нужно составить баг-репорт плана разработки сайта, где описано лишь что нужно сделать, что делается, что сделано и архив. Можно ли в данном случае пропустить шаги и ожидаемые результаты? Если нет, то как их можно описать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Сам Багрепорт есть некая форма отчетности, так сказать, результат проведенного тестирования на соответствие полученого результата Требованиям. В котором должны быть "Ожидаемый результат" и "Фактический результат". Я опускаю другие позиции Багрепорта, которые есть тоже важными, но все же исполняют дополнительную функцию.

План разработки - список необходимых действий для того чтобы сделать какой то продукт (в данном случае сайт). И составляется План разработки кем-то, и составляется, как правило, так как он того хочет и как это видит с точки зрения выбраной им модели ЖЦПО и личного жизненного опыта. Это мысли человека перенесенные на какой то носитель.

Из Вашего вопроса не понятно как Вы собираетесь тестировать "План разработки" на наличие ошибок.

Из Требований Вы берете "Ожидаемый результат", а из результатов теста берете "Фактический результат". Только так будет понятно выявлены ли разбежности или нет.
На то он и Багрепорт чтобы показать ошибку.

Если додумать Ваш вопрос и представить, что есть составленный План разработки, и Требования, то Ваш Багрепорт будет например содержать:

*Ожидаемый результат* - "План разботки должен соответствовать такой то модели ЖЦПО и состоять из таких пунктов:... и пошло перечисление."
*Фактический результат* - "Отсутствуют такие-то пункты. Присутствуют такие-то лишние пункты.".

Это о-о-очень упрощенно описал. Надеюсь получилось доступно.